# jQuery - Ajax requests not start in Intel XDK app

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, wordpress, cordova

I have a problem with the Intel SDK.  I wrote code in jQuery to login into the Wordpress platforms, and when I test my app with simulation it works well.

But when I use debug or build the ajax requests doesn't work and i don't understand why.

I tried to configure the white list of my proect in this way:

- Network Request ():  *, http:\*, https:\*
- Intent (): *, http:\*, https:\*
- Navigation (): // BLANK

I use CORDOVA CLI Version 6.2.0, how can I do for work my Ajax request??

This is my Ajax code ( It work in simulate mode )

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://test.com/oauth/token',
    crossDomain: true,
        data : {
            'client_id' : 'XXXXXXX',
            'client_secret' : 'XXXXXXX',
            'grant_type' : 'password',
            'username' : username,
            'password' : password
        },
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('XXXXXXX' + ':' + 'XXXXXXX') );
           },
        success : function(response) {
             var expiredAt = new Date();
                expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt.getSeconds() + response.expires_in);
                response.expires_at = expiredAt.getTime();
                localStorage.setItem('ls.token', JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log(expiredAt);
                $.cookie("Authorization", "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ls.token")).access_token, { expires: expiredAt } );


        },
    error : function(response) {
        $('.general-error').removeClass('hidden');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.general-error').addClass('hidden');
            }, 2500);
    }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to add your ajax code to this post along with any error messages you have seen.

Comment: @MisterPositive the problem is not ajax code but i think Cordova's whitelist.. Add the ajax code in the description

Comment: Add this to your error to see perhaps a more specific error message

error: function (request, status, error) { alert('Error: ' + error);

Comment: Status code: 404 not found @MisterPositive